# Method to calculate the most frequent last name from list of given users with Java Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, option-type

Function should return optional of most frequent last name (if it encountered at least two times) or optional empty if number of last names is the same or list of users is empty

This is what i came up with, but it doesnt return Optional.empty

```
@Override
public Optional<String> getMostFrequentLastName(final List<User> users) {
            return users.stream()
                .map(User::getLastName)
                    .distinct()
                .collect
                        (Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Function.identity(),
                                Collectors.summingInt(w -> 1)
                        ))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(stringIntegerEntry -> stringIntegerEntry.getValue() >= 2)
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .findFirst();
}
```

This is my test class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<String> optionalS = Stream.of(new User("name1"),
             new User("name1"), new User("name2"), new User("name2"))
            .map(User::getLastName)
            .collect
                    (Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Function.identity(),
                            Collectors.counting()
                    ))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(stringIntegerEntry -> stringIntegerEntry.getValue() >= 2)
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst();
    System.out.println(optionalS.toString());
}
```

> Here is the awnser

```
Optional[name2]
```

But should be

```
Optional[empty]
```

Comment: `name2` *is* encountered at least two times here and *is* found by `findFirst`... requirements are a bit un-clear may be? (ex student at UTM btw, feels good that once in while someone from my university pops up here!)

Comment: Why do you use distinct() in the first snippet? It returns unique elements so you can't count repeated values.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, i agree, but i just started learning streams and didnt know how to return Optional, so i used findFirst

Comment: this is not about that, at all. are your requirements to return `Optional::empty` if there are lastNames with the *same* count also?

Comment: Instead of `.map(User::getLastName) .collect  (Collectors.groupingBy( 
 Function.identity(),  Collectors.counting()  ))` you can simply use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getLastName, Collectors.counting()))`, but anyway, the question remains, why do you think that the code should produce an empty optional?

Comment: @Eugene, yes, indeed
if number of last names is the same or list of users is empty -> Optional.empty
else Optional[mostFrequentLastName]

Comment: @Holger, It`s my task)) But if list is empty if gives optional, im more interested in the question how to make it return an Optional on provided confition

Comment: Ok, so you are aware that the code so far did not do anything in that regard. Well, I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55181520/2711488).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
Optional<String> optionalS =
Stream.of(new User("name1"), new User("name1"), new User("name2"), new User("name2"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getLastName, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() >= 2)
        .reduce((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue() < e2.getValue()? e2:
                            e1.getValue() > e2.getValue()? e1:
                            new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(null, e1.getValue()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey);

System.out.println(optionalS.toString());
```

Getting the maximum value is a form of *Reduction*. Since you want to get an empty optional in case of a tie, the simplest solution is to write the reduction function explicitly, use the `Map.Entry` with the bigger value if there is one, otherwise construct a new `Map.Entry` with a `null` key.

The result of the reduction is already an `Optional`, which will be empty if there were no elements (with a count `>=2`). So the last `map` step is applied on an `Optional`. If already empty, the `map` function won’t be evaluated and the resulting `Optional` stays empty. If the optional is not empty, but `Map.Entry::getKey` evaluates to `null`, the resulting optional will be empty.

Comment: oh darn, I was soo close in my tests, why did I not think of that `null`!, very sweet!

Answer (score 1):

It *seems to me* that if you have the same number of maximum of some different lastNames you want to return an `Optional::empty`, as such:

```
Map<String, Long> map =
     Stream.of(new User("name1"),
               new User("name1"),
               new User("name2"),
               new User("name2"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getLastName, Collectors.counting()));

map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .max(Entry.comparingByValue())
   .flatMap(en -> {
           boolean b = map.entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .filter(x -> !x.getKey().equals(en.getKey()))
                          .mapToLong(Entry::getValue)
                          .noneMatch(x -> x == en.getValue());
           return b ? Optional.of(en.getKey()) : Optional.empty();
       })
  .ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I undestand your solution in stream you code creates

```
Map<String(lastname),Integer(number of occurence)>
```

and then filter that map where number of occurence >=2 and in your test case you have map with entries:

```
<"name1",2>
<"name2",2>
```

So ordering by value will still return two values.

You should try create

```
Map<Integer,List<String>>
```

which will store number of occurence -> names, then filter map keys, sort them descending and (in map value) you will get most frequently lastname (or lastnames if there were more than once in input).

//edit

Below short snippet with my solution:

```
  Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(2,Arrays.asList("name1","name2"));

    Optional<String> optionalS = map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .findFirst() //get max{map's keys}
            .filter(x->x.getValue().size() == 1) //get lastname that occured only once
            .map(x->x.getValue().get(0)); //get that lastname (above filter check that list has only one element) or Optional.empty if stream didn't find any

    System.out.println(optionalS.toString());
```

I skipped the part of creating map.

P.S. You can replace HashMap with TreeMap with custom comparator to avoid sorting in stream.

Comment: *Function should return optional* first four words in the question

Comment: Ok, i got you idea, but here after sorting i will have Map<2, List.of(name1,name2)> but this doesnt solve my problem, i cant return Optional from that, i think

Comment: @mario45211 ok, now i see what you was talking about. That`s indeed a nice solution! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here my monster for you:

```
    Optional<String> optionalS = Stream.of(
            new User("name1"),
            new User("name1"),
            new User("name2"),
            new User("name2"))
            .map(User::getLastName)
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Function.identity(),
                            Collectors.counting()
                    ))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(stringIntegerEntry -> stringIntegerEntry.getValue() >= 2)
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Map.Entry::getValue,
                            Collectors.toList()
                    ))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findFirst()
            .filter(x -> x.size() == 1)
            .map(x -> x.get(0).getKey());

    System.out.println(optionalS);
```

Comment: Ooooookey, your answer works) Could you explain what you did here `.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findFirst()
            .filter(x -> x.size() == 1)
            .map(x -> x.get(0).getKey());`

Comment: This part check that for number of duplicates there is only one name with that number and then get that name.